# For each $n >2$ find all $m \in \mathbb N$ such that there exist a group $G$ of order $m$ and a surjective homomorphism $f: A_n \rightarrow G$

Tags: abstract-algebra

For each $n >2$ find all $m \in \mathbb N$ such that there exist a group $G$ of order $m$ and a surjective homomorphism $f: A_n \rightarrow G$<

I tried to use the theorem of isomorphism, and a find $m = \dfrac{n!}{2|\ker f|}$

But I can't find $|\ker f|$, and I don't think that's the purpose of the exercise. 
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hint:  the kernel of a homomorphism is always a normal subgroup.

Comment: Second hint:  Break this up into the case $n=4$ and $n\ne 4$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By isomorphism theorem and Lagrange, we have that $|G| = \frac{|A_n|}{|\ker f|} = \frac{n!}{2|\ker f|}$.

Now, use the fact that kernel is a normal subgroup. Obvious options are $m = 1, \frac{n!}{2}$ since the trivial subgroup and the whole group are always normal. These values of $m$ correspond to $G = 1$ and $G = A_n$.

$A_3$ is cyclic group in three elements, and has no other normal subgroups.

$A_4$ is known to have a normal subgroup isomorphic to Klein four-group $V_4$, which has order 4, with factorgroup isomorphic to $A_3$. So, in this case $m = 3$ and $G = A_3$.

$A_n$ for $n \geq 5$ are known to have no non-trivial proper normal subgroups.